# An error with MySQL

Tags: server, internet, mysql

`An exception occurred: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`
This is what I get when I try to visit one site! The question is: is it releated to my computer or server? When I look at `/var/run/`, there ain't any mysqld folders! And if it is releated to my PC, could recent MySQL update(I think it was yesterday as today I recieved the Java 6 and 7 SDK update)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a server issue. The MySQL server seems to be down on the related host.

Comment: So that means it will just get fixed and return back? Glad to hear that!

Comment: Yes. Hopefully. Let's pray that nothing lethal happened on the server. :)